# Convert x265 Video to x264 and copy all audio tracks and subtitles

Tags: ffmpeg

i am converting x265 video having two audio streams and sutitles too, I am using this command but it create output file without video stream and with one audio stream and one sutitle, so what i am missing here

```
!ffmpeg -ss 00:03:00 -i "input file x265.mkv" -t 00:00:50 -c:v libx264 -crf 18 -map 0:a -map 0:s -c copy "output file x264.mkv"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only told it to copy audio and subtitles. Assuming you want **all** video, audio, and subtitle streams use:

```
ffmpeg -ss 00:03:00 -i "input file x265.mkv" -t 00:00:50 -map 0 -c copy -c:v libx264 -crf 18 "output file x264.mkv"
```

- `-map 0` selects all streams from `input file x265.mkv`.
- `-c copy` sets [stream copy](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-copy) mode for all selected streams.
- `-c:v libx264` overrides `-c copy` for all video streams, and encodes all video with libx264.

Result: Stream copy all stream types except video. Encode video to H.264 using encoder libx264.

See [FFmpeg Wiki: Map](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Map).